# C++ compiler error concerning a supposedly undeclared function

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, shunting-yard

I'm currently writing a basic program to evaluate mathematical expressions which I will then later use in genetic programming to determine the best solution to a system of expressions. My compiler keeps complaining but I'm almost sure that I've got everything right.

The error:

```
C:\Users\Baelic Edeyn\Desktop\Project\Equation\Shunting yard\Better>make  
g++ -g -c Shunt.cpp  
g++ -g -c main.cpp  
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':  
main.cpp:18:19: error: 'shuntingYard' was not declared in this scope  
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

My Makefile:

```
main: Shunt.o main.o  
    g++ -g Shunt.o main.o -o main  
main.o:main.cpp  
    g++ -g -c main.cpp  
Shunt.o:Shunt.cpp  
    g++ -g -c Shunt.cpp
```

My main:

```
#include "Shunt.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string expr = "3+ 47 *2/(1-5)^2^3";
    string expr1 = "a+b";
    string expr2 = "(a+b)";
    string expr3 = "a+b*!3";
    string expr4 = "(a+b)*!3";

    cout << "expression" << "   " << "postfix" << endl;
    cout << expr << "   ";
    shuntingYard(expr);
    cout << expr << endl;
    cout << expr1 << "      ";
    ...
    return 0;
```

}

My header file:

```
#ifndef SHUNT_H
#define SHUNT_H

#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Shunt
{
    public:
        int precedence(char);
        void shuntingYard(string &expr);
        bool isFunction(string);
        bool isOperator(char);
        bool isLeftAssociative(char);
        bool isNum(char);

    private:    

};

#endif
```

My implementation file:

```
#include "Shunt.h"

using namespace std;

void Shunt::shuntingYard(string &expr)
{
    ...
}
```

Please help I'm at the brink of chucking my laptop against the wall.

Comment: *C++ compiler error concerning a supposedly undeclared function*... when in disagreement with the compiler, I suggest you take the *humble stance* and assume that it is right (in this case, the function is undeclared). I'm not saying that compilers don't have bugs, but chances are that the origin of the issue is somewhere between the keyboard and the chair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shuntingYard()` is a non-`static` member function: you need an instance of `Shunt` on which to invoke it:

```
Shunt s;
s.shuntingYard(expr);
```

An alternative is make the member function `static` which does not require an instance of `Shunt` and can be invoked:

```
Shunt::shuntingYard();
```

Given that you deem it possible to invoke `shuntingYard()` without an instance making it `static` seems the more appropriate action. Or, if `Shunt` is being used to hold loosely related functions that share no state and do not represent the features of a specific abstraction is may be more appropriate to use a namespace instead of a class.

Comment: Thank you for the insanely fast reply!! Using it in a namespace rather than a class has worked wonders!!

Answer (score 1):

`shuntingYard` is not a free function, but a member function. You'll need to call it from an instance of the class:

```
Shunt s;
s.shuntingYard(expr);
```

You can make it a `static` member of the class and call it as:

```
Shunt::shuntingYard(expr);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are calling it like a regular function when it is actually a member function and as such you need an instance of `Shunt` to call it on.

Answer (score 0):

You've declared `shuntingYard` as the member function of an object but you're attempting to call it as if it was a free function.

You need to create a new `Shunt` class:

```
Shunt my_shunt;
my_shunt.shuntingYard(expr);
```

Comment: That should be `my_shunt.shuntingYard(expr);` as `my_shunt` is not a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Main doesn't know what `shuntingYard(expr)` is. You'll have to create an object of type `Shunt` before you call `shuntingYard(expr);` on that object.